# Modifed version of the knapsack

Tags: c++, algorithm

I know how to code the solution for the 0-1 knapsack problem. However, I do not know how to change this code such that we can pick multiple copies of the same item. So, for each item i , we have another paramter k(i) which denotes the number of copies of i present. I will be obliged if someone could help me with this. Below is my code when k(i) = 1. Look at the knapsack function for a top down dp solution

```
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int n, g;
int p[1005],w[1005];
int dp[1004][35];// num of object and weight left

int knapsack(int resourcel, int item){
    //if(resourcel < 0) return (1<<31);
    if(item == n) return 0;
    if(resourcel == 0) return 0;
    if(dp[item][resourcel] != -1) return dp[item][resourcel];

    if(resourcel - w[item] < 0){
        dp[item][resourcel]  = knapsack(resourcel,item+1);
        return dp[item][resourcel];
    }
    else{
        int take = knapsack(resourcel - w[item],item+1) + p[item];
        int notTake = knapsack(resourcel,item+1);
        dp[item][resourcel] = take > notTake?take : notTake;
        return dp[item][resourcel];
    }


}
int main(){
    int tc,dummy, sum =0;
    //freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    scanf("%d",&tc);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < tc; i++){
        sum  = 0;
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        scanf("%d",&n);
        //cout<<" n is : "<<n<<endl;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < n ;j++){
            scanf("%d %d",&p[j],&w[j]);
            //cout<<" price and val  is : "<<p[j]<<" " << w[j]<<endl;
        }
        scanf("%d",&g);
        //cout<<"g is : "<<g<<endl;
        for(int p = 0 ; p< g;p++){
            scanf("%d",&dummy);
            sum+= knapsack(dummy,0);//wight allowed and item visited
        }
        printf("%d\n",sum);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The most simple modification is to duplicate the copies - if there are 2 items then create 2 duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your knapsack code is overly complicated. Here is another way to do it:

Let `dp[i] = maximum profit we can get for weight i`.

```
for i = 1 to numItems do
  for j = knapsackWeight down to items[i].weight do
    dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j - items[i].weight] + items[i].profit)
```

Now, you also want a field `item.copies`. We can simply add another loop in the middle to iterate this many times.

```
for i = 1 to numItems do
  for k = 1 to items[i].copies do
    for j = knapsackWeight down to items[i].weight do
      dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j - items[i].weight] + items[i].profit)
```